# How to browse local Java App Engine datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

It seems there is no equivalent of Python App Engine's _ah/admin for the Java implementation of Google App Engine.

Is there a manual way I can browse the datastore? Where are the files to be found on my machine? (I am using the App Engine plugin with Eclipse on OS X).

Answer (score 111):

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/07/google-app-engine-for-java-sdk-122.html: "At long last, the dev appserver has a data viewer. Start your app locally and point your browser to <s>`http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin`</s> `http://localhost:8000/datastore`* to check it out."

* as of *1.7.7*

Comment: New admin interface is still not working with kinds/entities created by Native Datastore API. So I still need my "viewer" :)

Comment: http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin worked like a champ for me (note the port changed) - but I will try out the AppWrench just for comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I really needed this to debug a persistence issue.

Answer (score 40):

<strike>There's currently no datastore viewer for the Java SDK - one should be coming in the next SDK release. In the meantime, your best bet is to write your own admin interface with datastore viewing code - or wait for the next SDK release.</strike>

Java App Engine now has a local datastore viewer, accessible at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`.

Comment: This is redundant -- see dfrankow's post above.

Comment: You mean the link to the blog post that was posted several days _after_ I posted this reply? 'outdated' I'll accept, but redundant and voted down is a bit cruel.

Comment: I agree. Good answer at the time; now outdated.

Comment: @mcherm this one worked for me. The other answers here, on the other side, didn't.

Answer (score 6):

I have local datastore on my Windows+Eclipse environment on \war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin

As far as I understood it uses internal format named "protocol buffers". I don't have external tools to present the file in human-readable format.

I'm using simple "viewer" code like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws IOException 
{

    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    final DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    final Query query = new Query("Table/Entity Name");
    //query.addSort(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);

    for (final Entity entity : datastore.prepare(query).asIterable()) {
        resp.getWriter().println(entity.getKey().toString());

        final Map<String, Object> properties = entity.getProperties();
        final String[] propertyNames = properties.keySet().toArray(
            new String[properties.size()]);
        for(final String propertyName : propertyNames) {
            resp.getWriter().println("-> " + propertyName + ": " + entity.getProperty(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is good, but the parameter for the query constructor is wrong: Table is not correct, it mus be the Entity name. In the guestbook example it would be "greeting" which is the row. I tried this, but not working:final Query query = new Query("Guestbook/Greeting"); Another issue:
How do you show the content of different keys/names of a table with your code? Like guestbook1, gb2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the newest versions of the SDK (*1.7.6+*) the admin part of the dev server comes with it changed its location

Analyzing the server output logs we can see that it is accessible at:

`http://localhost:8000`

And the *Datastore* viewer:

`http://localhost:8000/datastore`

Looks pretty neat - according to google's new design guidlines.

Answer (score 1):

Because Google App Engines Datastore viewer does not support displaying collections of referenced entities, I modified Paul's version to display all descendant entities:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String entityParam = req.getParameter("e");

    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    final DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    // Original query
    final Query queryOrig = new Query(entityParam);
    queryOrig.addSort(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);

    for (final Entity entityOrig : datastore.prepare(queryOrig).asIterable()) {

        // Query for this entity and all its descendant entities and collections
        final Query query = new Query();
        query.setAncestor(entityOrig.getKey());
        query.addSort(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);

        for (final Entity entity : datastore.prepare(query).asIterable()) {
            resp.getWriter().println(entity.getKey().toString());

            // Print properties
            final Map<String, Object> properties = entity.getProperties();
            final String[] propertyNames = properties.keySet().toArray(new String[properties.size()]);
            for(final String propertyName : propertyNames) {
                resp.getWriter().println("-> " + propertyName + ": " + entity.getProperty(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted that nothing is displayed for empty collections/referenced entities.

Comment: This code looks for all your entities and their child entities, what if the child entities have children too ? will this function run as recursion ?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin` file with a text editor, like Notepad++.

The data is scrambled but at least you can read it and you can copy to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to do the login using below `gcloud` command

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```