# Google App Engine local datastore viewer not working?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I learned about how to browse my local App Engine Datastore from [this handy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102449/how-to-browse-local-java-app-engine-datastore). But now I'm using App Engine on a new machine, and the URL http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin is not working? It returns a 404 NOT_FOUND. My App Engine instance is definitely running on port 8888. I also just updated to the latest version. Any idea on why it's not working on what I can do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't using the right App Engine SDK. View the project properties, and under Google/App Engine change the SDK to the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Your url is incorrect. It should be http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

Comment: Right right, typo on my part in the question. But I really was trying the right URL, and it's not working.