# GUI for Google AppEngine DataStore

Tags: google-app-engine, user-interface, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a GUI for Google AppEngine DataStore ? 
I'm looking for something similar to phpMyAdmin.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in your app dashboard, on the left you see section Data. In that click on datastore viewer. Ofcourse this works if your app is hosted on app engine, for local server see, [How to browse local Java App Engine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102449/how-to-browse-local-java-app-engine-datastore)

Answer (score 4):

appengine.google.com has its own datastore viewer. where you can login and view the complete datastore for all your applications. In the development server, appengine SDK emulates the same. You can access it like http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin